# HTML characters from a downloaded page dont appears correctly

Tags: java, html, character-encoding

Some pages have HTML special characters in their content, but they are appearing as a square (an unknown character).

What can I do?

Can I convert the String containg the carachters to another format(UTF-8)? It's in the conversion from InputStream to String that happens this. I really don't know what causes it.

```
public HttpURLConnection openConnection(String url) {
    try {
        URL urlDownload = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) urlDownload.openConnection();
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        con.connect();
        return con;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private String getContent(HttpURLConnection con) {
    try {
        return IOUtils.toString(con.getInputStream());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Erro baixando página: " + e);
        return null;
    }
}

page.setContent(getContent(openConnection(con)));
```

Comment: Could you include your current code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the `InputStream` using [`InputStreamReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) with the charset as specified in the `Content-Type` header of the downloaded HTML page. Otherwise the platform default charset will be used, which is apparently not the same as the HTML's one in your case.

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8");
// ...
```

You can of course also use a HTML reader/parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org) which takes this automatically into account.

```
String html = Jsoup.connect("http://stackoverflow.com").get().html();
```

---

**Update**: as per your updated question, you seem to be using `URLConnection` to request the HTML page and `IOUtils` to convert `InputStream` to `String`. You need to use it as follows:

```
String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
String charset = "UTF-8"; // Default to UTF-8
for (String param : contentType.replace(" ", "").split(";")) {
    if (param.startsWith("charset=")) {
        charset = param.split("=", 2)[1];
        break;
    }
}

String html = IOUtils.toString(input, charset);
```

---

If you're still having problems with getting the characters right, then it can only mean that the console/viewer where you're printing those characters to doesn't support the charset. E.g., when you run the following in Eclipse

```
System.out.println(html);
```

Then you need to ensure that the Eclipse console uses UTF-8. You can set it by *Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text File Encoding*.

Or if you're writing it to some file by `FileWriter`, then you should rather be using `InputStream`/`OutputStream` from the beginning on without converting it to `String` first. If converting to `String` is really an important step, then you need to write it to `new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8")`.

Comment: With the Jsoup still the same thing, but I will try with the InputStreamReader.

Comment: Then it's the viewer/console which doesn't support the charset. Where are you printing/viewing the HTML content? In Eclipse console for example? You need to configure it to support UTF-8. Or are you writing it to file? Then you need to use the same charset in the `Writer`. For more background information, check http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html

Comment: Ok, I know what I have to do now, but in some pages, the encoding is not in the charset attribute, but in encoding or another (differences between HTML, XHTML, etc.) There is some class to get it automatically? I using HTMLParser to parse HTML. I used ISO-8859-1 in a page with problems and it was solved. Now I only need get the encoding in the pages.

Comment: Jsoup does it automatically. Your problem is in the way how you print/save the HTML string.

Comment: I using Postgres and before I convert it correctly, in the database the String are appearing wrong too. After the conversion, the now appear correctly.

Comment: So you're storing the HTML in the database? You need to set UTF-8 encoding in the DB and table.

Comment: Already it's UTF-8. The conversion with IOUtils.toString(input, charset) worked perfectly, but I need pass to it the right enconding. The question now is how do I get the encoding without downloading the page before. If I download it, I must convert it to String, set in a HTML parser, get the encoding and then, convert it again.

Comment: So your current issue is solved and your new issue is converting the pages which are downloaded before? That's in essence a brand new question. Anyway you can get it by a `HEAD` request on the URL. It will return a response with only the headers without the body.

Comment: Yes, it's a new question. I will open it in a new "thread". Thank you, was a great help.